# How read a file (JSON) from directory without storing it as a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I've a problem with the serialization of JSON.

I need to pass a JSON file from a directory, without generating a JSON string, because the file automatically updates every 5 minutes.  All the solutions that I've seen ask me to pass the JSON file as a string, like this:

```
string json="{ \"test\":\"some data\" }";
```

The language that I'm using is C#.  I've already installed the class: "Newtonsoft.json.dll". My project is a Web-Services in VisualStudio 2012.  Can anyone tell me how to do this without saving the JSON file as a string?

If you want more information, please tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I entirely understand your issue, however maybe you can do something like:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("fileName.json"))
{
    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json);
}
```